# Execute method in service sub object with Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire

I want to launch a method in a sub object of a service in background with Hangfire. So this is what I do.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyService>(myService => myService.SubObject.MyPublicMethodAsync());
```

But it throw an exception because `MyPublicMethodAsync` is in `SubObject`and not in `IMyService` because of this validation code in HangFire :

```
  if (!method.DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(type.GetTypeInfo()))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"The type `{method.DeclaringType}` must be derived from the `{type}` type.",
                    typeParameterName);
            }
```

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Common/Job.cs (line 391)

My current workaround is to do that :

```
public Task DoWhatIWant()
        {
            return _myService.SubObject.MyPublicMethodAsync();
        }
```

And

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DoWhatIWant());
```

But it's very ugly so do you know a proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260836/scheduled-tasks-limitations-or-how-tasks-persistence-is-implemented), Hangfire tasks are serialized as a single method call. You can't write a complicated expression like that; it's simply not supported.

You can get around the issue by writing a method and calling it directly, like this:

```
class MyService : IService
{
    public void DoWhatIWant()
    {
        this.SubObject.MyPublicMethodAsync();
    }
}

BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IService>( s => s.DoWhatIWant() );
```